# Verifying complete response from cURL

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

Sometimes when using multiple concurrent connections and scraping with cURL in my PHP script, incomplete webpages are returned.  Is there some value in `curl_getinfo()` that will let me know if a webpage was 100% fetched vs. only 90% fetched?

Would the content-size header of a returned page be the actual size of what was returned or would it be the entire page?  If so, I could check the content-size against the actual size of the response..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question is whether you can check if the content size header comes from the other side or is calculated on your side, yes, you can use that header to check if you've received the full response because it is generated on the other side from the actually intended content. A few things, though:

- It's `Content-Length`, not `Content-Size`;
- you can use it as long as you trust the other party to set it correctly;
- it may not be available because while it SHOULD exist, it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Exactly what I was looking for. +1 for tips.